# '!' in input buffer in comparison in if statement

Tags: c, string, gcc, char

I am not clear with the usage of `!` in input buffer comparison in the below sample code

```
/*GLOBAL VARIABLES*/
int pipe_count=0, fd;
static char* args[512];
char *history_file;
char input_buffer[1024];

int main()
{
    int status;
    char ch[2]={"\n"};
    getcwd(current_directory, sizeof(current_directory));
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
   while (1)
    {
      clear_variables();
      prompt();
      fgets(input_buffer, 1024, stdin);
      if(strcmp(input_buffer, ch)==0)
            {
              continue;
            }
      if(input_buffer[0]!='!')
            {
                fileprocess();
                filewrite();
            }
      len = strlen(input_buffer);
      input_buffer[len-1]='\0';
      strcpy(his_var, input_buffer);
      if(strcmp(input_buffer, "exit") == 0)
            {
              flag = 1;
              break;
            }
```

I am not able to understand `if(input_buffer[0]!='!')`

In this statement what does `'!'` mean in comparison does it signify a `NULL` 
or it is some thing else. The full code is very big, this is just one part which I am not clear with.

I checked the ASCII value of `!` from [here](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html) but I am not able to understand what is `input_buffer[0]` being compared against by using `!` in code for a `NULL` etc I as far as I understand it is `NULL`, `'\0'`, `' '`. This kind of `input_buffer[0]!='!'` thing is not clear to me as to what it gets translated to?

I am **not asking** about the *not equal* to operator here, i.e. `if (condition1 != condition2)` I understand how it's working. However here in *condition2* there is `'!'` which is what I am asking. What does this signify?

Comment: Maybe just the way the program accepts its commands.

Comment: meaning of it is - if user enters `'!'` character at the beginning of input - file processing must be skipped. So it's just a way of the code author for skipping file processing

Comment: @ace you got it correct program is accepting commands the ! character at the beginning of input when will this be true if I execute program as 
./a.out  command1 command2 command3

Comment: You should test the return value from `fgets()` before processing the input.  You might have received no new data because it encountered EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many uses of `!` operator in Linux.
See this [article](https://www.tecmint.com/mysterious-uses-of-symbol-or-operator-in-linux-commands/).

In your case, it is probably to check if the a command from history is given as input.
See the first point of the article.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just `!`, but `!=` together and is known as the *not-equal to* operator.
As its name signifies, it is the opposite of `==` operator.

In your case `if(input_buffer[0]!='!')` the `if` statement will be `true` if `input_buffer[0]` is *not equal to* `'!'`.

The second occurrence represents the character `'!'`, which has an ASCII value of 33.

In your example, what it signifies is the trigger to process and write the file. Only when the first character in the buffer is not `'!'` is when the processing will happen.

Comment: no you look further after that there is '!' in the comparsion i.e. !='!' I am asking about the '!' in the condition

Comment: yes now you got it right but what is not equal to '!' signifying when commands are being taken as input to be passed on to a shell in a C program.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as it looks like - a literal `!`. If the line starts with anything but a `!` the author wants to do

```
fileprocess();
filewrite();
```

Maybe there's some difference between "commands" that start with an exclamation point (they are comments or something like that? or, if this is a shell of some sort, it's doing something different - such as not updating the history - as [it may be related to history expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3747/12167)?) and all the rest? Without seeing the rest of the code and knowing the context it's hard to say.

Comment: yes you got it right history of commands being passed is saved in a file and this ! is used there